# Rails 6, devise is doing nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

rails newbie here using devise to create users for my rails 6 app.

I followed the steps outlined here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise but when I try to sign into my app, the `log in` button does nothing (with valid credentials of course).  Nothing happens in my logs so theres nothing interesting to show.  This also happens with the `sign up` button when you register a new user.

I have looked through many other SO pages but they are from the past and I wonder if rails 6 has a different solution.

Here is some relevant code:

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stocks
  has_many :stocks, through: :user_stocks
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb (Same issue with the log in):

```
<h1><%= t('.sign_up') %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9>"
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'current-password', class: 'form-control' %>

        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
          <small class="form-text text-muted"><%= t('devise.shared.minimum_password_length', count: @minimum_password_length) %></small>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'current-password', class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit t('.sign_up'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render 'devise/shared/links' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

app/controllers/application.rb (This helper forces you to log in/sign up):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user_stocks
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'welcome#index'
  get 'my_portfolio', to: 'users#my_portfolio'
  get 'search_stock', to: 'stocks#search'
end
```

db/migrate/[timestamp]_devise_create_users.rb:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Logs provided here,  I navigated to .../my_portfolio to demonstrate that it pushed me to the log in page, but when I enter valid credentials and press "log in", nothing happens in the logs.

```
$ rails s
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.7.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-07-15 20:33:30 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
   (0.8ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 2.7ms | Allocations: 713)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 31.9ms | Allocations: 5455)
/Users/kevinjay/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:355: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/Users/kevinjay/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:118: warning: The called method `[]' is defined here
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (Duration: 3.0ms | Allocations: 112)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 198)
Completed 200 OK in 154ms (Views: 125.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms | Allocations: 24815)


Started GET "/my_portfolio" for ::1 at 2020-07-15 21:35:15 -0700
Processing by UsersController#my_portfolio as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms (Allocations: 388)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-07-15 21:35:16 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 169)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.7ms | Allocations: 1077)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 5)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 29)
Completed 200 OK in 79ms (Views: 72.8ms | Allocations: 6463)
```

Thank you, any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: What do the rails logs say?

Comment: I added logs to the main post due to word count limits.

Comment: Try commenting out `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your application controller and try to sign in again.

Comment: It's hard to see what goes here. Anyway, this is a [bare devise application](https://github.com/imhta/rails_6_devise_example). It's worth to clone it and try. It might solve your issue.

Comment: @hashrocket, when I comment out the line in application_controller.rb the "log in" or "sign up" buttons still don't work.

Comment: Check your console. Are you getting any errors there when you press `log in`?

Comment: Nothing happens to the console with `before_action :authenticate_user!` commented out or not.  I see it loads .../user/sign_up, I enter credentials, and then nothing happens.